# what are pmxi tables?

Tags: multisite, database

I'm on multisite mode. I can see that for each site of the network there are 4 'pmxi' tables. What are they for?

They're something like this

siteprefix_pmxi_files
siteprefix_pmxi_imports
siteprefix_pmxi_posts
siteprefix_pmxi_templates

Comment: Those belongs to WP All Import/export plugin

Answer (score 12):

This doesn't sound like something coming from WordPress core.

Quick search online got pretty slim results, but it *seems* to be asscociated with WP All Import plugin.

Comment: You're right. They are WP All Import tables: https://plugintests.com/plugins/wp-all-import/3.4.6